# iPhone 4s stuck in apple logo while downgrading to iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

My iPhone 4s is around 10 years old. I use it daily. It was on iOS 9.3.6. I wanted to downgrade to iOS 6. I installed Phoenix jailbreak and then put it in KFDFU and flashed 3utools IPSW.

But the flash failed and iPhone was not getting recognised back. I waited for 3-4 hours then I decided to unplug and plug it back, still no success.

My iPhone is now stuck in iOS 6 logo with a progress bar. Home button is broken; I used to use assistive touch with it. I took backup of the phone on my MacBook but the phone is not getting recognized by MacBook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while the phone was still one , I Unplugged the battery by removing the back panel and using non conducting material to pull the battery connector tab. iPhone powered off and then reconnected the battery , and powered it on. It booted back to ios 9.3.6 but It was glitching ( maybe because of currupted file system? ) then i used a tool called imyfone to put iPhone in recovery mode ( home button not working ) and then restored it to previous backup .

Comment: Um...ok.  it booted back to *what* exactly?  It's helpful if you provide context to what you're doing so as to assist future readers with this same problem.

Comment: @Allan fixed it , hope it helps.